# spring hibernate many-to-many mapping form input

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need help with my many-to-many mapping, I want to add a list if items, into a class via a form. I am working on a dabase for movies and actors, and in the 'Movie' class I have a list that contains the actors in that movie, the list is mapped to the 'Actor' class.

This is for adding a movie:

```
<body>
Add Movie
<form:form modelAttribute="movie">
Title:
<form:input path="title" /><br />
Rating:
<form:input path="rating" /><br />
Year:
<form:input path="year" /><br />

<form:select path="actors">
    <c:forEach items="${actor}" var="p">
        <form:option value="${???}">${p.name}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>

<input type="submit" value="Save movie" />
```

First I enter the values for the new movie (title, rating and the year it was released),  then I have a select form, wich lists a set of actors, the thought is to select what actors that are in the movie, but I don't know how to do it.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Movie showMAddForm(Model model){
    List<Actor> actor = actorService.list();
    model.addAttribute("actor", actor);
    return new Movie();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveMAddForm(Movie m){
    movieService.saveMovie(m);
    return "saved";
}
```

What do I have to do, to be able to select what actors I want in the newly created movie?

EDIT: This is my Actor class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Actor {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int actor_id;
private String name;
private String age;
private String link;

private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();

// Setters and Getters

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "actors")
public List<Movie> getMovies(){
    return this.movies;
}

public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies){
    this.movies = movies;
}

}
```

And this is the Movie class, so you can see how the mapping is

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Movie {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private int movie_id;
private String title;
private String rating;
private String year;

private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<Actor>();

// Setters and getters

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = com.springapp.mvc.Actor.class)
@JoinTable(name= "ActorList", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="actor_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="movie_id")})
public List<Actor> getActors(){
    return this.actors;
}
public void setActors(List<Actor> actors){
    this.actors = actors;
}

}
```

Comment: So basically, you want to enter a few actors and save them in the database, correct? Is the actors table mapped to some other table? Can you please post your model code for Actors class

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I want to 'select' some actors in the form for creating a 'movie', think you can help?

Comment: Ok, you want to add actors I presume...can you tell me how are you mapping it..I can post some code which can help you with one to many association...

Comment: in mysql the mapping is over another table, called 'actorList' wich stores what actor is in what movie. You can see that in the 'movie' class that I posted

Comment: Now I saw your edit...oh...I have code as one-to-many...I think you need to DAOImpl method, I have posted that below, you can use that one, it will work for you too...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need this exactly, but I am trying, so if there is any problem, let me know, I will edit as per your requirement :

person model class : Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements UserDetails{

 @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "person_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq_gen",sequenceName = "person_seq")
    private int id;

    @Valid
    @NotEmpty @Email(message = "email.empty")
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Valid
    @Size(min = 6)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password may not be empty")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person1",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Canvas> canvas1 = new HashSet<Canvas>();

    public Set<Canvas> getCanvas1() {
        return canvas1;
    }

    public void setCanvas1(Set<Canvas> canvas1) {

        this.canvas1 = canvas1;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "canvas")
public class Canvas {

    @Id
    @Column(name="canvasid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "canvas_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "canvas_gen",sequenceName = "canvas_seq")
    private int canvasid;

    @Column(name = "canvasname")
    private String canvasname;
 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id",nullable = false)
    private Person person1;

    public Person getPerson1() {
        return person1;
    }

    public void setPerson1(Person person1) {
        this.person1 = person1;
    }

    public int getPerson1id(){
        return this.person1.getId();
    }
}
```

PersonDAOImpl :  This class saves person in database :

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    private Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session){this.session = session;}


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPerson(Person p) {

        if( session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        session.saveOrUpdate(p);

    }
}
```

CanvasDAOImpl : This class saves canvas

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class CanvasDAOImpl implements CanvasDAO{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    private Session session;

    public void setSession(Session session){this.session = session;}

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @Override
    public void addCanvas(Canvas canvas, Person person) {
        int id = person.getId();
        if( session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        Person person1 = (Person) session.get(Person.class,id);
        person.getCanvas1().add(canvas);
        canvas.setPerson1(person1);
       session.merge(canvas);

        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Controller methods :

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@Valid Person person,BindingResult bindingResult,@ModelAttribute("person") Person p,Model model){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

            model.addAttribute("errors",bindingResult.getAllErrors());
            return "redirect:/";
        }

            this.personService.addPerson(p);
            return "redirect:/";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/canvas/add")
    public String addCanvas(@ModelAttribute("canvases") Canvas canvas,Model model){
The method below uses Spring Security to find out who is logged in.
        Person person = personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
        model.addAttribute("canvases",new Canvas());
        model.addAttribute("listCanvas", this.canvasService.listCanvases());
        model.addAttribute("listCanvases",this.canvasService.listCanvasPerson(person));
        this.canvasService.addCanvas(canvas,person);
        return "redirect:/canvas/list";
    }
```

Comment: That is some quick coding, I have a way of creating actors (persons), but they are not connected to a movie. So when I create a movie (see my initial post) I list all available 'actors', and when I select one of them, I want it to be added to the list of actors to that movie. I know I might not make sense, but thanks for trying!

Comment: ahh...I think I am starting to understand you now..You see a list of Actors, and when you click 'add' button, the Actor gets added in 'Movie' List..Correct?

Comment: If yes, then you can use something similar to CanvasDAOImpl..I am positive it will work.